# Proof for factorization lemma

Tags: measure-theory

I am confused by the proof of [Factorization lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_lemma).

Specifically the part "f is a step function" confuses me.

$f$ has a representation where all $A_i$ are disjunctive. I prefer to work with this representation further on.

The proof constructs $g$ and claims that this function is exactly what we need:

1. $g$ is $\sigma(T)-\mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$ measurable
   (and it is clear because $\forall i$ $A'_i \in \mathcal{A}'$),
2. $f=g \circ T$ (and that I do not see).

Indeed, take $\omega \in A_i$, then it follows $f(w)=\alpha_i$, also follows that $T(w) \in A'_i$, but there might be $A'_j$ such that $T(w) \in A'_j$ because sets $A'_i$ must not be disjunctive as we assumed for sets $A_i$. Thus $g \circ T(w)=\alpha_i+\alpha_j \ne f(w)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I see where you problem lies. Assume you have a step function

$$
f=\sum_{i=1}^n  \alpha_i 1_{A_i} 
$$
where $A_i \in \sigma(T)$ and for $i\ne j$ we have $A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset$. We may choose such a representation as you pointed out. Since $T$ is measurable (I am referencing to the Wikipedia link) by construction, we have 
$$
\forall i \text{ there exists }A^{'}_i\in \mathcal{A^{'}} \text{ such that } A_i=T^{-1}(A^{'}_i) 
$$ 
But if we assume that the $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ are disjoint, so are the $(A^{'}_i)_{i\in I}$. And therefore no contradiction occurs.
Why is that:

Let's say $A_i=T^{-1}(A^{'}_i)$ and $A_j= T^{-1}(A^{'}_j)$ with $A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset$. Now assume  $A^{'}_j\cap A^{'}_i = C \neq \emptyset$ and take $x\subset C$, then we have 
$$
T^{-1}(x)\subset A_i \text{ and } T^{-1}(x)\subset A_j \Rightarrow A_i\cap A_j\neq\emptyset
$$
which would be of course a contradiction.

bests

Comment: I am afraid the argument you are using is wrong. To see that note that you in your answer above at one point write  $A_i=T^{-1}(A^{'}_i)$ and later $A_i=T(A^{'}_i)$. So in one part of your answer you see $T$ as $T:\Omega \to \Omega^{'}$ and in another $T:\Omega^{'} \to \Omega$. Because of this substitution the argument seems to work, but I am afraid it actually does not.

Comment: Oh sorry, that's actually I typo...I forgot to add the inverse, thanks for pointing out

Comment: @ user190080 Will you edit the answer?

Comment: @SergeyZykov I just did :)

Comment: @ user190080 Perfect thanks a lot, can not believe that I got confused over such a basic thing.

Comment: *corrected* what if $T^{−1}(x)=\emptyset$ in your last line? In the statement, $T$ need not be surjective...

Comment: @FernandoVieiraCostaJúnior ok, good question: if $T^{−1}(x)=\emptyset$ then you need to choose a different $x^{'}\subset C$ for which we have $T^{−1}(x^{'})\ne\emptyset$, then you'll get your contradiction. Such an $x^{'}\subset C$ exists since we assumed that $A^{'}_j\cap A^{'}_i = C \neq \emptyset$ (use $T(\emptyset)=\emptyset$ and $T^{-1}(\emptyset)=\emptyset$)

Comment: @user190080 sorry. I can't understand what you said, again because  $T$ may not be *onto*. We can only affirm that $T(T^{-1}(A))\subset A$, not the converse. It happen if and only if T is surjective.

Comment: @FernandoVieiraCostaJúnior not quite sure I get your problem: in the above setting, we have put $A_i=T^{-1}(A^{'}_i)$ - the mentioned line really just proves then that if $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ are disjoint, so are the $(A^{'}_i)_{i\in I}$.

Comment: @user190080 And I am telling you that we can have $A_1=T^{-1}(A_1')$ and $A_2=T^{-1}(A_2')$ disjoint with $A_1'\cap A_2'\neq\emptyset$. These elements don't belong to the image of $T$.

Comment: @FernandoVieiraCostaJúnior I am rather confident that my argument works, but I could ofc be mistaken: you might consider to ask a new question (referencing to this question/answer) or write a new answer to the question yourself. (but maybe the problem is too isolated, so you better just go ahead and post a new question). I'd be happy if you would let me know.

Comment: @user190080 please take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

The sets $A'_i$ have not to be disjunctive. So it is true that if $x\in A'_i\cap A'_j$ (assuming that $x\notin A_k, k\neq i,j$), then $g(x)=\alpha_i+\alpha_j$. But this is not a problem. When we compose $g\circ T$, the function $g$ will take only values in the image of $T$, then things like $(g \circ T)(w)=\alpha_i+\alpha_j$ can't happen. To see this and conclude that $g\circ T = f$, let $x\in \Omega$. So $T(x)\in\Omega'$.

First suppose that $x\in\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$. Then $x\in A_i=T^{-1}(A_i')$ for some $i\in\{1,2,...,n\}$, that is, $T(x)\in A_i'$ and $T(x)\notin A_j'$ for all $j\neq i$ in $\{1,2,...,n\}$. In fact, if $T(x)\in A_j'$, then $x\in T^{-1}(A_j')=A_j$, what implies $x\in A_i\cap A_j$, that is, $i=j$. Nice. So $g(T(x))=\alpha_i=f(x)$ for all $x\in\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$.

Now, take $x\in\Omega\backslash(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i)$. Then $T(x)\notin A_i'$ for all $i\in\{1,2,...,n\}$. In fact, if $T(x)\in A_i'$ for some $i\in\{1,2,...,n\}$, then $x\in T^{-1}(A_i')=A_i$, what is an absurd $(x\notin\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i)$. Therefore $g(T(x))=0=f(x)$ for all $x\in\Omega\backslash(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i)$.

Thus $g\circ T = f$, as we wanted.

You can find a nice proof of this theorem in the book Measure and Integration Theory by Heinz Bauer. Consider ask a new question to clarify new misunderstandings about the proof.